# iOS - [ObjC] NavigationBarButtonItem is not showing when the navigation bar's root view is presented modally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I have two tabs that handle different set of functions.

One tab is the user tab, when the user switch to this tab, the tab controller checks whether the user has logged in. If not, it shows a button(`LoginBtn`) which triggers a log in view controller to show when tapped.

I intend to present the log in controller modally with a navigation bar.

However, the navigation bar is not showing the right button item although I've initiated it.

Here's the code

```
- (void)clickLoginBtn{
    LogginController* _cLogginController = [[LogginController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *_cNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_cLogginController];

    _cNavController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"取消" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissLoginView)];
    [_cNavController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:kColorWhite];
    _cNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:_cNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

What could be the problem? Is it possible that is because I present to controller modally?

Comment: Why don't you put this code in the `LogginController` `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @New16 Actually I've tried that, but it didn't work. Perhaps it is because I added the controller inappropriately, but I haven't find the answer yet.

Comment: @Jinglei.Y try my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have put your buttons to the login controller:

```
_cLogginController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"取消" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissLoginView)];
```

You shouldn't add navigation items to the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.I think this issue is solved by this code

```
- (void)clickLoginBtn{
    LogginController* _cLogginController = [[LogginController alloc] init];
    _cLogginController .hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=No;//You need to add this line

    UINavigationController *_cNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_cLogginController];

    _cNavController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"取消" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissLoginView)];
    [_cNavController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:kColorWhite];
    _cNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:_cNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Still no button. Thanks for your answer anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    DemoViewController * _cLogginController = [[DemoViewController alloc]init];
    _cLogginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DemoViewController"];
     _cLogginController .hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
    UINavigationController *_cNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_cLogginController];
    _cNavController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _cNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
   _cLogginController.navigationItem.title = @"取消";
   UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Flip"
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(flipView:)];
    flipButton.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    _cLogginController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
  [self presentViewController:_cNavController  animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: output]